# In LTE CUPS architecture, when will the SX/PFCP session establishment is triggered?

Tags: lte

Everywhere in LTE call flow and 5G call flow, I see that Sx or PFCP session establishment is triggered upon a initial-attach from UE reaching the control-plane.

My question is, PFCP or SX is node level association, right ? PFCP or SX session can be established even before the UE's anchored/attached to the PDN-GW, right ?

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon browsing I found out that there are two procedures happening between control-plane and user-plane in CUPS architecture.

1. Node level association - PFCP association setup and responses.
2. Subscriber session level PFCP - PFCP session establishment and modification which carries the subscriber's allocated IP addresses via the PDR IE and their QOS properties via QER.

So, the type#1 mentioned above procedures takes place even before any subscriber is attached to the PDN-GW. And the type#2 procedures is per subscriber session level.